# what firestore security rules are applied on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I applied recently to most of my firestore collections allow read and write only if user is authenticated.
however, I am implementing some google cloud functions (scheduled functions and on document creation functions) to do some changes on these collections (create new documents and update some others). I am not sure if the cloud function will be able to do so after these rules.

is google cloud function considered authintacted? or what rules are applied in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions run Server-Side as admin. They completely surpass Firestore rules.
You shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I have the read access using "auth != null". When i run firebase functions i'm getting permission denied. But works fine when i change the rule to ".read": true.

Any ideas?